# How to rotate window in X11

Tags: x11, window-manager, window, xmonad

Is it possible to rotate a single window in X11? I tried to use Xephyr but I run into [bug 100458](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100458).

I use XMonad as WM if that helps.

Comment: I don't think there's a way in general. There was an experimental plugin/extension for Compiz a while ago that allowed for that, but I don't know its name or current state

Answer (score 3):

I've searched around a bit and I'm surprised not to find a ready solution for this.
A possibility could be to use KWin and write a "Kwin effect" for it: https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-write-a-kwin-effect/ . 
Also, a gnome shell extension is imaginable, but does not exist yet.

A workaround solution:
Weston is the reference implementation of Wayland. It allows rotating windows with super-key + middle mouse button. 
As this works for Wayland clients only, you can run Xwayland in weston, run your X application on Xwayland, and rotate the Xwayland display.
If your application supports Wayland (based on GTK3, QT5 or SDL, for example), this works in weston without Xwayland.

For X applications on Xwayland

```
weston
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 Xwayland :5
DISPLAY=:5 yourXapplication
DISPLAY=:5 x-window-manager  # additionally run a window manager for comfort
```

(On Gnome-Wayland you can run Xwayland directly without using weston, but I'm not aware of a Gnome-Wayland option to rotate a window).

For QT5 applications without Xwayland:

```
weston
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0  QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland  yourQT5application
```

For GTK3 and SDL applications without Xwayland:

```
weston
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 yourGTK3application
```

(Note: You can specify a wayland socket/WAYLAND_DISPLAY with `weston --socket=mywaylandsocket` instead of assuming it will be `wayland-0`. You need to do this on Gnome-Wayland as it uses `wayland-0` itself)

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a second answer using Weston, a bit different and more useable than my first one. 
Create a file `~/.config/weston.ini` with this content:

```
[core]
modules=xwayland.so
shell=desktop-shell.so
idle-time=0
[shell]
background-color=0xff002244
locking=false
# panel-location=none    
[launcher]
icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/apps/utilities-terminal.png
path=/usr/bin/weston-terminal
[launcher]
icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/firefox.png
path=/usr/bin/firefox
[output]
name=X1
mode=600x800
transform=90
# wanna get mad? use: transform=flipped-270
scale=1
```

This `weston.ini` enables a rootless `xwayland.so` in weston. 
The `[output]` section with `name=X1` defines weston's appearance as X client.

- `mode=600x800` sets the screen/window size.
- `transform=90` rotates the weston display.
- `scale=1` sets a scaling factor if needed.
- the `[launcher]` sections can be used to create custom panel starters for your X applications.

See `man weston.ini` and `/usr/share/doc/weston/examples/weston.ini` for further informations and options.

(Instead of using the weston panel, you can disable it with `panel-location=none`, parse output of weston for `xserver listening on display :1` and use `DISPLAY=:1 yourXapp`)